# How can I define a relationship so that it can only have exactly two entries in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: sqlalchemy, constraints

I have two tables DOOR and ROOM (s. below) where each door should be associated with exactly two rooms and each room can be associated with one or more doors.
How can i define this constraint with SQLAlchemy?

```
door_room_association = Table('association:door-room',
                              DeclarativeBase.metadata,
                              Column('door_id', ForeignKey('door.id'), primary_key=true),
                              Column('room_id', ForeignKey('room.id'), primary_key=true))

class Door(DeclarativeBase):
    id: Column(String, primary_key=true)
    locked: Column(Boolean)
    rooms = relationship('Room', secondary=door_room_association, back_populates="doors")

class Room(DeclarativeBase):
    id: Column(String, primary_key=true)
    name: Column(String)
    doors = relationship('Door', secondary=door_room_associaiton, back_populates="rooms")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the Python level, you could listen for [events](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/events.html#sqlalchemy.orm.AttributeEvents.append) that modify the number of doors related to a room.

```py
@sa.event.listens_for(Room.doors, 'append')
def door_append_handler(target, value, initiator):
    if len(target.doors) == 2:
        raise ValueError('Too many doors')
```

Since this is at the Python level, it won't prevent doors being added by processes outside of your application.  If you need that level of protection, you could consider adding a trigger (perhaps using the [custom DDL](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/ddl.html#custom-ddl) construct).  The DDL for the trigger may vary by database.