# Is there a way to create computational relationships in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I would like to add business rules to an SQLAlchemy relationship similar to how you would in a hybrid attribute. In particular, I would like to add maximum multiplicity rules, eg. User object can be related to a maximum of five Post objects.

Is this possible, if not are there any alternatives?

Comment: Limiting related to User objects is a bussiness logic part and thus have nothing to do with a databases and sqlalchemy

Comment: @sudden_appearance I understand that yet, SQLAlchemy still supports hybrid classes which allow you to implement business logic within the SQLAlchemy classes so I guess the question remains is there any comparable workaround?

Comment: Similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70788972/how-can-i-define-a-relationship-so-that-it-can-only-have-exactly-two-entries-in

Comment: @snakecharmerb thank you that's exactly what I was looking I'll close my question.